# Checking Win7 ISO veracity - Win7IsoVerifier says its not ok

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

My laptop HDD broke. I bought new HDD. I is Asus n53sv so I dont have Windows 7 installation DVD, I had only the preinstalled Windows7 and I have product key. Since the hdd is unusable I must download new Windows7 ISO.
 I am trying to download it from here: microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7 and i put product key there and it says Error: The product key you entered appears to be for software pre-installed by the device manufacturer. Please contact the device manufacturer for software recovery options.

I've downloaded Win7 ISO not from MS pages, I check its veracity and I have doubts:
The Win7ISOVerifier says that: The specified ISO file is not recognized Windows 7 image. I installed it on USB HDD and it boots OK but before using it I must check its veracity.

```
MD5: C30DDF270DA6E5D00A03AF794C27298A
SHA1: 1700A1C8BA8EE07F21609C8DBD7A4CDF4CCC257F
SHA256: 9C9470837778ECC436E04D075539AA8F9E65D269804C3B5F85401160A6A9B9FE
SHA512: 21B088358FEFD40A68948C7B460CAC5B504E550263FE5900FDBE1E5AA69F82D125AEAF29955C9C7AE22E8623272136130FB4559B60C9AE705BF5BC9613E52F82
```

Where are the ISO checkums to check? Why Win7ISOVerifier doesnt recognize it?

Comment: Here's your problem: "I've downloaded Win7 ISO not from MS pages". Unless you get it from MS (or a trusted supplier) you shouldn't trust it's genuine.  So why not go get it from [Microsoft directly](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows7)?

Comment: I updated the post, there is a reason why not MS pages.
I have one last idea - I also have Acer laptop with Win7 also preinstalled. There is a system recovery DVD which I could create and install that Windows7 on my laptop and provide my product key. Is it a good solution, do u have any better?

Comment: You're probably going to have to get a new license anyways, so you might as well go get one, then go back to Microsoft for the Win7 download. That's the best way to make sure everything is good.

Comment: Perhaps do as it suggests and contact Asus and enquire about getting install DVDs from them?

Comment: The SHA1 checksums are on MSDN. Give me the full name of the version it's supposed to be (32bit, 64 bit, home, pro, N, K, ...) and I can check.

Comment: I quickly looked and didn't see your checksum but there are 60 iso files just for for the english version, I could have missed it. Give the language and version.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned, download it from the [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows7) website. It's not hard for someone to modify an ISO to add whatever they want to it and still have it fully functional, so be warned if not using a genuine site.

Note also that Win7IsoVerifier is unlikely to have been maintained to cover all distributions out there now, so isn't necessarily a problem...

From Win7ISOVerifier site (dated 2009):

> Update 3: With the wider public release of Windows 7, **this tool is no
>   longer kept up to date** with the many and numerous versions of Windows
>   7 SKUs and languages. It is recommended you take personal care when
>   using any ISOs.

Comment: He's right - the Verifier is not updated anymore, so new versions wouldn't be covered.

Comment: Where is the MS website for download? Only one I've found asks me for product key and then error appears before download, just like I quoted in the first post.

Comment: Microsoft only has downloads for retail versions of Windows, they took down all the oem download links long ago.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Win7 ISO Verifier only works correctly for English versions. So you may have a non-English version that is perfectly fine, but the Verifier won't recognize it.

Source: [Win7ISOVerifier](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090706/windows-7-iso-verifier/)

Also, in regards to your license key: The OEM key probably won't work on a new install of Windows. You'll likely need to purchase a new license key (which Microsoft is no longer selling, so you'll have to go through a 3rd party).

Comment: Its EN version however I've noticed 2009 note, saying that it is no longer kept up to date..

Comment: OEM keys do work on Windows 7 systems as long as it's the same edition.